# Take the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In console of chrome in developer tools if I type this help.eventType I can see the value.

In google tag manager what variable should I fire to take this key/value?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do a push of this value into the dataLayer, in order for GTM to be able to access it:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'someEvent',
    'someVar': help.eventType
})
```

I've included an ambiguous event as well, so that you can trigger any tags off of that.